# There are many exceptions for the mnemonic rule of thumb "i before e except after c" but have any new attempts arrived at any new rule?

Tags: spelling, mnemonic

Per title, there are many exceptions for the mnemonic rule of thumb "i before e except after c". Have any new attempts arrived at any new rule? For example, compile all the cases of a consonant sandwiched between two vowels and create new rules with statistics.

Comment: "Some research" could include typing your question into a search engine and reading the first few hits, for instance, then editing your answer to include what you found.

Comment: I remember seeing on QI (a panel show in the UK) that there are more words which break the rule 'i before e except after c' than words which follow it.

Comment: The mnemonic as I learned it was longer: "'i' before 'e' except after 'c', or when sounded like 'a' as in 'neighbor' and 'weigh'. "  That actually captures a significant further common case in a short and still rhyming phrase.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of spelling rules:

> Q is always followed by u

> Magic e makes the vowel long

> When adding "ing" remove the magic e, or double the final consonant.

and so  on

These aren't found by statistical processes but by simple description of trends in English words and the mistakes that children (native speakers of English) often make. Any rule which would require statistical analysis to discover would not be very useful: Either it would give some information that isn't a common mistake *"b" is never followed by "n" at the start of a syllable* or is too specific *"F-something-"A"-something-"K" is never followed by "O"*.

The "i before e" rule is actually pretty good, when applied only in those cases in which "ie" represents an /i:/ sound. The "after c" part of the rule comes from a single family of words, all derived from Latin via French.

Comment: The unfortunate fact is that English—even more than some other languages—was not created around a set of rules, but mutated and morphed as disparate languages collided. Any attempts to constrain its spelling around orderly, logical consistencies has come along fairly recently in its history.

Comment: @Andy see the famous "English is three other languages in a trenchcoat/English mugs other languages in dark alleys and rifles through their pockets for loose grammar" tweets. In any case, I've heard the expanded form of the mnemonic: "*i* before *e*, except after *c*, **or when sounded as *a* as in 'neighbor' or 'weigh'**."

Comment: @randomhead "[And on weekends](https://youtu.be/QWzYaZDK6Is?t=54), and holidays, and all throughout May, and you'll always be wrong no matter what you say!"